# Can I get some sample output from react-native-device-info?

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

This repo (https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#usage) looks like it has some methods for accessing device information through react native.

Does anyone have some sample output data from actual devices?

It would be nice to just get an idea of what the data looks like without having to compile and run it on a bunch of devices.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I got from running it on several devices and emulators.

Following are specific method calls from DeviceInfo, and the resulting output. I changed some of the identifying values, but left the format of  each value exactly as it was output from the device. I didn't output every method available on DeviceInfo, just the ones that were useful to me at the moment. Hope this helps someone:

(a Kindle Fire)

```
getDeviceName:  Name of My Kindle Fire
getUniqueID:    123ba45a678901a2
getManufacturer:    Amazon
getModel:   KFAUWI
getSystemName:  Android
getSystemVersion:   5.1.1
getBrand:   Amazon
getAPILevel:    22
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; KFAUWI Build/LVY48F; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/59.0.3071.125 Safari/537.36
isTablet:   true
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 1
getVersion: 0.0.0
getReadableVersion: 0.0.0.1
```

(a Samsung Galaxy S8)

```
getDeviceName:  Name of My Phone
getUniqueID:    f12edc3b4af56e78
getManufacturer:    samsung
getModel:   SM-G950U
getSystemName:  Android
getSystemVersion:   8.0.0
getBrand:   samsung
getAPILevel:    26
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G950U Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.70 Mobile Safari/537.36
isTablet:   false
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 1
getVersion: 0.0.0
getReadableVersion: 0.0.0.1
```

(an avd emulator running a Pixel C tablet)

```
getDeviceName:  Unknown
getUniqueID:    9a876b5432109cde
getManufacturer:    unknown
getModel:   Android SDK built for x86
getSystemName:  Android
getSystemVersion:   5.1.1
getBrand:   Android
getAPILevel:    22
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Android SDK built for x86 Build/LMY48X) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/39.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
isTablet:   true
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 1
getVersion: 0.0.0
getReadableVersion: 0.0.0.1
```

(an iPhone emulator, launched from xCode)

```
getDeviceName:  nameofmyapplemachine
getUniqueID:    48FC4A5D-D189-6623-6DB2-B28CCC88D10D
getManufacturer:    Apple
getModel:   iPhone 6
getSystemName:  iOS
getSystemVersion:   11.4
getBrand:   Apple
getAPILevel:    not available
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15F79
isTablet:   false
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 11
getVersion: 0.0.11
getReadableVersion: 0.0.11.11
```

(an iPad emulator, launched from xCode)

```
getDeviceName:  nameofmyapplemachine
getUniqueID:    DA6BEB1C-7C8D-9DD3-CA46-C06AD59E55DF
getManufacturer:    Apple
getModel:   iPad Air 2
getSystemName:  iOS
getSystemVersion:   11.4
getBrand:   Apple
getAPILevel:    not available
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 11_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15F79
isTablet:   true
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 11
getVersion: 0.0.11
getReadableVersion: 0.0.11.11
```

(an iPad 2 physical device)

```
getDeviceName:  Name of My iPad
getUniqueID:    AD059D5A-E0D4-3326-6F0C-B8DAB8A5CA6F
getManufacturer:    Apple
getModel:   iPad 2
getSystemName:  iPhone OS
getSystemVersion:   9.3.5
getBrand:   Apple
getAPILevel:    not available
getUserAgent:   Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 9_3_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/13G36
isTablet:   true
getApplicationName: My Awesome App
getBundleId:    com.app.awesome
getBuildNumber: 11
getVersion: 0.0.11
getReadableVersion: 0.0.11.11
```